# Accessing angular ngform status in parent component

Tags: forms, angular, validation

This is the Parent HTML

```
<parent-component>
    <child></child>
    <button type="submit" [disabled]="!childForm.valid">
</parent-component>
```

This is Child HTML

```
<child>
    <form #childform=ngform>
      <input required type="text">
    </form>
</child>
```

I need to access the childform status in the parent component

Answer (score 9):

**Child template:**

```
<form #childform=ngForm>
  <input required type="text">
</form>
```

**Child component:**

```
export class ChildComponent implements OnInit {

  @Output() validityChange = new EventEmitter<boolean>();
  @ViewChild('childform') form: NgForm;
  private validStatus: boolean;

  ngOnInit() {
    if (!this.form) return;
    this.form.valueChanges
      .subscribe(_ => {
        if(this.validStatus !== this.form.valid) {
          this.validStatus = this.form.valid;
          this.validityChange.emit(this.form.valid);
      });
  }
}
```

**Parent template:**

```
<child (validityChange)="childFormValid = $event"></child>
<button type="submit" [disabled]="!childFormValid">
```

**Parent component:**

```
export class ChildComponent implements OnInit {

  private childFormValid: boolean;

  ...
}
```

Comment: Thanks Man!!! You are really a genius and you gave the exact code what is needed!!! Saved my day!!!

Comment: Glad I could help! Please accept the answer since it helped :) @Khirthan

Comment: Excellent, simple solution.

Answer (score 4):

Probably you could do it using @ViewChild:

Child component template file:

```
<form #form="ngForm">
  <input type="text" ngModel required name="input">
</form>
```

and use @ViewChild  in child component TS file like this:

```
@ViewChild('form') form: NgForm;
```

Parent component template file:

```
<button type="submit" *ngIf="childForm" [disabled]="!childForm.valid">Submit</button>
```

and in your parent component TS file reference to child component as well:

```
export class ParentComponent implements AfterViewInit {

  @ViewChild('child') child: ChildComponent;
  public childForm;

  ngAfterViewInit(): void {
    this.childForm = this.child.form.form;
  }
}
```

Comment: Ya this is working but i have scenario where iam calling the childcomponent 2 times and the second form submit button is always disabled.

it gets enabled only, when the 1st form valid is true, its kind of tricky!!!

Answer (score 0):

Use an output

```
<child (myOutput)="myFunction($event)"></child>
```

In your parent component :

```
myFunction(event: Event) {
    console.log(event); // hello world
}
```

In your child component

```
import { Output, EventEmitter } from '@angular/core';
// ...
@Output() myOutput: new EventEmitter();

doSomething() {
    thisMyOutput.emit('hello world');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Child Component

```
export class ChildparentComponent implements OnInit {

  @Output() toParent = new EventEmitter<string>();

  constructor() { }

  onChange(value:string){
    this.toParent.emit(value);
  }
```

In Child Html

```
<app-childparent (toParent)="childValue = $event"></app-childparent>
```

In Parent

Access this child value in parent template like  `{{childValue}}`

A working example of the Same

```
https://rahulrsingh09.github.io/AngularConcepts/#/inout
```

Its Backend Code

```
https://github.com/rahulrsingh09/AngularConcepts/blob/master/src/app/parentchild/parentchild.component.html
```

Comment: This wouldnt work as i need to send the ngform object itself in disabled of parent component!!!

Comment: Then i would suggest you to go for services to share info 

 https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34376854/delegation-eventemitter-or-observable-in-angular2